# Big O notation of this function

Tags: recursion, time-complexity, big-o, asymptotic-complexity

```
function A(n):
    if n ≤ 10 then
        return 1 fi;
    x := 0;
    for i = 1 to n do
        x := x + 1 od;
    return x * A(n/3) * A(n/6) * A(n/4)
```

My first idea was, that every call of A(n/c) is in O(log n) and since each has a for-loop from 1 to n it should be O(n log n). But since each call of A() also evokes 3 more it should also be somewhat exponential, right?

Answer (score 2):

The calculation of `x` simply assigns `n` to it with `n` steps. So we can assume the loop is just a dummy `n` steps.

The rest of the function can be brought down to:

```
return n * (A(n/3) ** 3);
```

In every recursive step, A is divided by 3. This means we effectively get a sum of `n + n/3 + n/9 + ...` until `n/3` reaches < 0.5.

The whole thing needs to be multiplied by 3, but this itself won't change anything complexity-wise. Now such a sum (`E(i = 0, inf)` of `n/(k^i)`) converges to `n/k-1`, which is `O(n)` given a constant `k`. Of course doing actual divisions by 6 or 4 won't change anything either.

So the complexity of your entire function is `O(n)`.